# Tracing Letters

Tags: android, trace

Dear Android developers,
I want to create application to trace alphabet letters. I already have canvas and background image of letter I. And have following code for drawing letter:

```
  @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.moveTo(350, 170);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(350, 800);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

the problem is that when i press anywhere on the screen it automatically draws the line. but I want to make to start drawing the line when I put my finger on the start coordinate, then the line should follow my finger path and only if I will reach the end point line should be drawn. in other case I should start from the beginning. and the line should be straight line.
thank you

Comment: Hello, did you solve the problem?